# Hibernate Envers shared domain objects on different schemas with and without envers

Tags: hibernate, schema, hibernate-envers

We are currently still using Hibernate 4 also with Hibernate Envers. Our application is using two different db schemas, sharing the same domain objects. One of the schemas (`schema1`) are working with envers tables (`_aud` and `revinfo`), the others (`schema2`) not. In a few business cases, values will be copied from `schema1` to the identical tables in `schema2`

That means the envers table `revinfo` exists in the `schema1`, but not in the `schema2`. Somehow with Hibernate 4 that works fine so long. We are currenty upgrading our application to newer dependencies, as first step I am upgrading from `4.3.11.Final` to `5.0.12.Final` and facing the issue, that hibernate complains table `revinfo` is missing on `schema2`

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "schema2.revinfo" does not exist
Position: 13
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2182)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1911)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:173)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:622)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:472)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeUpdate(PgStatement.java:429)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:384)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
```

Comment: Are you specifying `org.hibernate.envers.default_schema` or `org.hibernate.envers.default_catalog`?

Comment: Hi Brian, there were no `default_schema` nor `defaut_catalog` defined. To make more clear, `schema1` should use envers, `schema2` not. I tried now to define `schema1` with `default_schema`, but then it complains about unique constraint in `revinfo_pkey`. I assume that now two schemas not use `schema1` for envers entry. The entity manager of `schema2` has configured `hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister=false`, currently I am also playing with `hibernate.integration.envers.enabled`

Answer (score 0):

What I did for now and it seems to work. The `schema2`had already configured

```
<prop key="hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister">false</prop>
```

I added there

```
<prop key="hibernate.integration.envers.enabled">false</prop>
```

Not neccassary but to make sure I added in EntityManager `schema1`also:

```
<prop key="org.hibernate.envers.default_schema">managed_configuration</prop>
```

I am not 100% sure yet about side effects. I will come back.

Comment: Our Jenkins Jobs works fine so far. It seems that we upgraded to 5.0 successful so far.

Comment: All you should have needed was to specify the `org.hibernate.envers.default_schema` property.  The others should have no impact on your situation at all.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The point is, one transaction manager on `schema1` should use envers, so `*.default_schema` is set, the other transaction manager on `schema2` should not use envers, but both sharing the same domain classes with hibernate-envers annotations. Thats why it is disabled.